# Distributed sum of numbers

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

I have a set of web apps running on different machines which have a set of metrics. I want a running sum for each of those metrics from each of the machines.These cumulative metrics will be used later. Hence, should be persisted, say, for each day. How would I approach this? This would be easy to do using Accumulator variables in Spark. But Spark can't be installed on these machines.

I think this also should be possible through Zookeeper. But, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead with using this:

http://netflix.github.io/curator/doc/com/netflix/curator/framework/recipes/atomic/DistributedAtomicLong.html

`Distributed Atomic Long` recipe in `Netflix curator`.